# String to byte[] with a defined size

Tags: java, android, arrays, encryption, realm

What i am trying to do is convert a `String` into a `byte[]` but i need the byte[] ***size*** to be **64 bytes** always, independently of what string is on the input in order to be used with Realm encryption. However, after some research, I couldn't find anything similar, or is there any other way I can use a string as the Realm encryption?

This is my code:

```
String passphrase = "ASDYB982234235512";
byte[] key = passphrase.getBytes();
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .encryptionKey(key)
                .build();
```

This is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provided key must be 64 bytes. Yours was: 17
```

Comment: Are you looking for a hash function?  What do you want to happen if the string is more than 64 bytes long?

Comment: Im looking for a way to use a string into the Realm encryption, if it's larger than 64 don't allow to use that string but if it's shorter, fill the blanks somehow with the same string for consistency

Comment: If the input string is less than 64 bytes long and it must be 64 bytes, somebody (perhaps Obama) must fill out the input until it is 64 bytes long.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a [Key Derivation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) to generate an encryption key from the user's passphrase. The simplest form of this is to add a salt to the user's passphrase and then feed it into SHA-2 to get a 256-bit hash, but ideally you want to use something like [scrypt](https://github.com/wg/scrypt) to make it harder to brute-force the passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

Here https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html you can find the function you can use (I just changed the key size):

```
public static SecretKey generateKey(char[] passphraseOrPin, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    // Number of PBKDF2 hardening rounds to use. Larger values increase
    // computation time. You should select a value that causes computation
    // to take >100ms.
    final int iterations = 1000; 

    // Generate a 512-bit key
    final int outputKeyLength = 512;

    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphraseOrPin, salt, iterations, outputKeyLength);
    SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    return secretKey;
}
```

And then use `secretKey.getEncoded()`.

To generate salt:

```
final Random secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
byte[] salt = new byte[32];
secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);
```

Remember to save the salt and keep it somewhere (in Preferences for instance).

Answer (score -1):

Try encoding the string using Base64.encode, i guess the output will be useful to you.

Or try using a string with 64 characters in it your current passphrase contains 17 characters

Comment: Already tried encoding to Base64 unfortunately it doesn't fill the 64bytes, and i cannot use a hardcoded string as the encryption string changes dynamically for each user

Comment: did you remove the extra padding that comes is the form of == while encoding via base 64  Try  encoding using base64 and use only the text and leave the == part  Or use NO_PADDING flag while encoding